# Flask | Python script output not displayed continuously

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to display output from Python script on a webpage with Flask. 
The output is correct but it waits for the script to end before displaying anything on the page.

```
def execute():
    foldername = request.form['foldername'] 
    def inner():
      sys.stdout.flush()
      cmd = "./deploy-config.py {}".format(foldername)
      proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

      for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline,''):
          yield line

    env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
    tmpl = env.get_template('deploy.html')
    return Response(tmpl.generate(response=inner()))
```

Template

```
<h4>Please wait ...</h4>
  {% block body %}
    <body>
      {% for line in response %}
        <p0>
        {{ line }}<br>
        </p0>
      {% endfor %}
     </body>
   {% endblock %}
```

How can I get the output to print continuously?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't in this way. Your template must be rendered all the way. Some data may be sent to your browser, but it won't be displayed until it's complete.

Here's some other questions like yours to give you a better starting point;

[How can you display the results of a script in real-time for a Django 1.4 website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045050/how-can-you-display-the-results-of-a-script-in-real-time-for-a-django-1-4-websit)

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6jx5ef/how_do_i_display_real_time_output_of_a_python/

What it comes down to is that you're going to reply with a webpage with some JavaScript. That script will continuously update the page with new information you need to publish on a separate 'view'.

Comment: Thank you. I am not familiar with Django and new to programming. The template does get rendered and prints <h4>Please wait ...</h4>. The response output is not printed.